# Haskell - Calling a function defined in a typeclass

Tags: haskell

Given a typeclass:

```
class AnimalTrainer animal food where
    getFood :: animal -> (food, Int) -- Returns the food and the quantity
    feed :: animal -> (food, Int) -- Returns the leftovers

    feed a = feed' (getFood a) -- Provide a default implementation
        where feed' (f, n) = (f, n - 1)
```

And an instance:

```
data Animal = Dog | Cat
data Food = Meat | Milk

instance AnimalTrainer Animal Food where
    getFood Dog = (Meat, 2)
    getFood Cat = (Milk, 3)
```

How can I write another function (somewhere else) that calls the feed function defined in the typeclass? Example:

```
feedEverything :: Bool
feedEverything = snd (feed Dog) == 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that Haskell can't figure out what type you want to use for food.  It sees one instance:

```
instance AnimalTrainer Animal Food
```

But maybe there is a second instance somewhere...

```
instance AnimalTrainer Animal Poison
```

So you need to tell Haskell that animals get food *only,* and not something else like poison.

**Solution 1:** You can use functional dependencies:

```
class AnimalTrainer animal food | animal -> food where
    ...
```

This tells Haskell that for each animal type, there is *only one* food type that it will eat.

**Solution 2:** You can also use type families.

```
class AnimalTrainer animal where
    type AnimalFood animal :: *
    getFood :: animal -> (AnimalFood animal, Int)
    feed :: animal -> (AnimalFood animal, Int)

    feed a = feed' (getFood a) -- Provide a default implementation
        where feed' (f, n) = (f, n - 1)

data Animal = Dog | Cat
data Food = Meat | Milk

instance AnimalTrainer Animal where
    type AnimalFood Animal = Food
    getFood Dog = (Meat, 2)
    getFood Cat = (Milk, 3)
```

I personally consider this solution a little more esoteric, and the syntax a little less natural.  But the example is contrived, so I include this for completeness.

**Solution 3:** You could add explicit type annotations whenever you call feed.

```
feedEverything = snd ((feed :: Animal -> (Food, Int)) Dog) == 0
```

Comment: BTW, you have to add a pragma to your file to make this work: `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}`

Comment: @FUZxxl: I left that out, since this isn't supposed to be a complete module and the poster's code doesn't compile without extensions anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another doubt, suppose that I can't modify the typeclass declaration (provided by a third party). Is it possible to make the function call to feed work by modifying just the call site (feedEverything)?

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, that is also possible.  I have added a third solution.  It is sometimes hard to reason with contrived examples, since words like "Dog", "feed", and "Meat" sound relevant but are not.  In the future, it might be easier to answer the question if you use names like X, Y, Z, f, g, etc.

Comment: I know what you mean, I sometimes struggle to find out what people really want or need when I see their code and try to answer their questions (about other languages, not Haskell which obviously I'm just beginning to learn). So I thought it would be better to give some context rather than use simple letters that (to me) don't mean anything. I guess that the best approach is to use the actual problem and don't try to come up with something similar which will almost certainly be contrived. BTW, your answer is excellent: both really complete and well structured. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In this case, I assumed that you could change the class definition, since "obviously, no library would contain a class for AnimalTrainer".